# Somehow $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] is not giving me the IP address of this one user..?

Tags: php

I've got a basic application form on my website that uses `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` to include the IP address of the user submitting the form.

I'm using the following in my form processor script.

```
// Create database object and connect to database.
$db = new Database($db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name);
$db->connect();

// Collect POST data
$merchant_data['ip_address'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$merchant_data['first_name'] = isset($_POST['first_name']) ? $_POST['first_name'] : '';
$merchant_data['last_name'] = isset($_POST['last_name']) ? $_POST['last_name'] : '';
$merchant_data['email_address'] = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
$merchant_data['phone_number'] = isset($_POST['phone']) ? $_POST['phone'] : '';
$merchant_data['customer_notes'] = isset($_POST['comments']) ? $_POST['comments'] : '';
$merchant_data['plan_name'] = isset($_POST['plan_name']) ? $_POST['plan_name'] : '';
$merchant_data['estimated_monthly_volume'] = $_SESSION['estimated_monthly_volume']; 
$merchant_data['interested_in'] = isset($_POST['interested_in']) ? $_POST['interested_in'] : '';
$merchant_data['additional_equipment_interest'] = isset($_POST['additional_equipment_interest']) ? serialize($_POST['additional_equipment_interest']) : '';
$additional_equipment_interest = isset($_POST['additional_equipment_interest']) ? $_POST['additional_equipment_interest'] : array();
$merchant_data['website_id'] = 1;

// Add new record in database.
$merchant_app_record_id = $db->query_insert('merchant_account_applications',$merchant_data);

// Close database connection
$db->close();
```

I've been getting some SPAM hits to this form lately by somebody, but somehow, this user's IP address is not getting logged in my system.

Every other user that goes through, though, does end up with the IP address logged.

What could this person be doing to make it so my site can't grab their IP address?  I want to ban their IP but I can't get it.

Any information on how to get their IP or another way to ban a particular user would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you possibly post the relevant part of your code? It would help... Alternately, you could disallow users that are not showing their IP address to post.

Comment: I updated the original post with the snippet of code that handles the database insert.  On the guy hitting me with SPAM, I end up with a record in my table that has everything filled out except for the IP address.  Any time I test it, though, and any time a different user fills it out I get their IP address included with their record no problem.

Comment: I was just thinking I could go ahead and add some logic where if I don't have an IP address value I don't add it to the database, but it would still nice to figure out how this guy is doing that.

Comment: Look at all those Related questions... odds are at least one of them will be helpful.

Comment: I suspect your webserver is misconfigured and is incorrectly trusting X-Forwarded-For from the client. What server is it? Do you have anything running in front of it like Varnish or Nginx?

Comment: I browsed through the related questions already and didn't find anything that was like what I'm getting.  

It's a managed VPS.  I'm not familiar with Varnish or Nginx.  Should I tell my server host to make sure it's not trusting X-Forwarded-For?

Answer (score 2):

Use this: https://gist.github.com/cballou/2201933

This works in my blog site. I don't know why $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] cannot handle this problem, but the snippet in the github works very well.

Answer (score 1):

I had this happen when a user was using a proxy (that he had set up himself) - instead of an IP address I was getting something like "neil@mars" because that's what he'd configured in his proxy.

In addition to

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

you can try

```
getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP')
```

Comment: In this case I'm just getting an empty value for this user's IP address.  Maybe they could simply be masking it with a proxy..??  I'll have to take a look at getenv() and see if that helps.  Thanks for leading me in a direction for now.

Comment: It would have been just as easy for this Neil guy to have sent a blank IP address as it was to send "neil@mars", it was just the way he'd configured his proxy server.

Comment: `getenv` sometimes is disabled for security reasons.

Comment: This may point you in the right direction, but it is not the answer to your problem. There's no way that REMOTE_ADDR could be wrong and X-Forwarded-For could be correct unless there is something really wrong about the way your webserver is set up.